# Number of distinct contiguous subarray

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

```
import math
n=7 #length of list
k=2 #number
arr=[1,1,1,1,4,5,1]
l=n

def segmentedtree(segmentedtreearr,arr,low,high,pos):  #function to build segment tree
    if low==high:
        segmentedtreearr[pos]=arr[high]
        return
    mid=(low+high)//2
    segmentedtree(segmentedtreearr,arr,low,mid,((2*pos)+1))
    segmentedtree(segmentedtreearr,arr,mid+1,high,((2*pos)+2))
    segmentedtreearr[pos]=segmentedtreearr[((2*pos)+1)]+segmentedtreearr[((2*pos)+2)]

flag=int(math.ceil(math.log2(n))) #calculating height of segment tree
size=2*int(math.pow(2,flag))-1#calculating size

segmentedtreearr=[0]*(size)


low=0
high=l-1
pos=0
segmentedtree(segmentedtreearr,arr,low,high,pos)
if (n%2==0):
    print (segmentedtreearr.count(k)+1)
else:
    print (segmentedtreearr.count(k))
```

Now arr=`[1,1,1,1,4,5,1]` so different possible combinations for sum equal to `k=2` can be `[1,1]` using index `(0,1)` and `[1,1]` using index `(1,2)` and `[1,1]` using index `(2,3)` but i am getting 2 as a output although my implementation is correct.

Comment: Sorry, l is equal to n ,edited the post.

Comment: Your segment tree is correct, but it is not implied that you can get the solution just by counting the occurrences of 2 in that tree. There are leafs in the tree that belong to different parents, but are adjacent in the array, so the segment tree will not have the sum stored for only those two.

Comment: then how should i proceed?

Comment: why don't you put some  break point and debug it

Comment: Are you actually counting those sequences that spread over multiple nodes?

Comment: What made you think that a segment tree was the right data structure for solving such questions? Was it suggested to you?

Comment: @HariomSingh Actually my segment tree is correct but when i am trying to find the possible combinations  for a given number it is not working correctly.

Comment: @trincot for a  single query segment tree works in o(log n) that's the fastest method ,isn't it?.

Comment: A lookup in a segment tree works in O(log n) if you have a query point. But you only have a sum, not a node.

Comment: Time complexity to query is O(Logn). To query a sum, we process nodes at every level and number of levels is O(Logn). This is actually faster than other implementation moreover fenwick tree is other implementation which can work faster .I tried fenwick tree and had success using it.

Comment: The problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/cognizant-2/challenges/siddhant-and-money/problem

Comment: My solution using fenwick tree which works fine :https://ideone.com/tUUM19

Comment: Segment tree for this problem is a huge overkill. there is a simple O(n) solution using two pointers. I can explain more if you want.

Comment: @noJS yes,please a different solution would be appreciated :)

Comment: @noJS My fenwick tree implementation passes all the test cases in max 0.01 sec.So i don't think segment tree would be a overkill.

Comment: @OmSharma, you write *"To query a sum, we process nodes at every level and number of levels is O(Logn)."*. Sure, visiting one node per level is a O(logn) action, but what I am saying is that you cannot get every set of adjacent nodes that produces the desired sum in that way. That is just not the right algorithm. Segment trees have a different purpose.

Comment: Not sure if this should be a comment or an answer, let me know if I should move it. The idea is to keep two pointers l and r, start with both l and r equal to 1 and sum=arr[1], now as long as sum is less than k, increase r and add arr[r] to sum, and while sum is more than k, subtract arr[l-1] and increase l. now check if sum=k and update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @OmSharma I didn't mean by overkill that it is slow, just too complicated for the problem.

Comment: @trincot okay,I get your point.But is there any way i can get this implementation to work correctly if not fast ? :p

Comment: Do you need to produce *one* range (which seems to be the question on hackerrank), *all* ranges, or the *count* of ranges?

Comment: @trincot count of  different possible contiguous arrays that sums up to k.

Comment: And is your question to get an optimal solution, or to get a working segment-tree based solution which cannot be optimal (just want to be sure not to waste my time on something you don't need in the end).

Comment: @trincot i want a working segment tree solution ,I already have an optimal solution.

Comment: I had a look at it, but I see no easy solution with segment trees, so essentially I am giving up on the idea.

Comment: the only solution that involves a segment tree I can think of is do a binary search from each index i to find the index that gives a subarray of sum k, and use segment tree to calculate the sum but that makes no sense because you can just use prefix sum to do it.

Comment: @noJS  your indexing starts from 1 or 0?

Comment: @trincot thank you for giving it a try,I am also giving up on this approach.

Comment: @OmSharma you mean the two pointer method? yes i assumed it starts with 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segment trees are good for looking up ranges when you have an absolute point, but in your case you have a relative measure you are looking for (a sum).

Your code is missing a pair of ones that are in two different branches of the tree:

[image]

As you can imagine, larger sums could span several branches (like for sum = 7). There is no trivial way to make use of this tree to answer the question.

It is much easier with a simple iteration through the list, using two indexes (left and right of a range), incrementing the left index when the sum is too large and incrementing the right index when it is too small. This assumes that all values in the input list are positive, which is stated in your reference to hackerrank:

```
def count_segments_with_sum(lst, total):
    i = 0
    count = 0
    for j, v in enumerate(lst):
        total -= v
        while total < 0: 
            total += lst[i]
            i += 1
        count += not total
    return count

print(count_segments_with_sum([1,1,1,1,4,5,1], 2)) # -> 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an O(n) solution discarding the tree approach. It uses `accumulate` and `groupby` from `itertools` and `merge` from `heapq`:

It is not very optimized. My focus was on demonstrating the principle and using vectorizable components.

```
import itertools as it, operator as op, heapq as hq
arr=[1,1,1,1,4,5,1]
k = 2
N = len(arr)

# compute cumulative sum (starting at zero) and again shifted by `-k`
ps = list(it.chain(*(it.accumulate(it.chain((i,), arr), op.add) for i in (0,-k))))

# merge the cumsum and shifted cumsum, do this indirectly (index based); observe that any eligible subsequence will result in a repeated number in the merge
idx = hq.merge(range(N+1), range(N+1, 2*N+2), key=ps.__getitem__)
# use groupby to find repeats
grps = (list(grp) for k, grp in it.groupby(idx, key=ps.__getitem__))
grps = (grp for grp in grps if len(grp) > 1)
grps = [(i, j-N-1) for i, j in grps]
```

Result:

```
[(0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4)]
```

Some more detailed explanation:

1) we build the sequence ps = {0, arr_0, arr_0 + arr_1, arr_0 + arr_1 + arr_2, ...} of cumulative sums of arr. This is useful because andy sum of a stretch of elements can be written as the difference between two terms in ps.

2) in particular, a contiguous subsequence that sums to `k` will correspond to a pair of elements of ps whose difference is `k`. To find those we make a copy of ps and subtract `k` from each element. We therefore need to find numbers that are in ps and in the shifted ps.

3) because ps and ps shifted are sorted (assuming the terms of arr are positive) the numbers that are in ps and ps shifted can be found in O(n) using `merge` which puts such pairs next to each other. If I remember correctly, the merge is guaranteed to be stable, so we can rely on the element from ps coming first in any such pair.

4) it remains to find the pairs which we do using groupby.

5) But wait a minute. If we do this directly all we got in the end are pairs of equal values. If you just want to count them that's fine, but if we want the actual sublists we have to do the merge indirectly, using the `key` kwd arg which works in the same way as in `sorted`

6) So we create two ranges of indices and use `list.__getitem__` as key function because we have two lists but can only pass one key, we concatenate the lists first. As a consequence the indices into the first and second list are unique.

7) the result is a list of indices `idx` such that ps[idx[0]], ps[idx[1]], ... is sorted (`ps` in the program is ps with ps-k already glued to it) using the same key function as before we can do the groupby indirectly, on `idx`.

8) we then discard all groups that have only a single element and for the remaining pairs shift back the second index.

Comment: Thanks,I guess i will need to look at the working of merge.

Comment: It takes `k` sorted inputs and sorts them together in `O(N log k)` our `k` in this case is `2`, so this is `O(N)`. But in practice it's more often than not slower than a simple `np.sort`.

Comment: So it does merge sort on the basis of index,right? Could you please explain why you merged list of range(n+1) and list of  range(n+1,2*n+2)?

Comment: Just because the `key` function wouldn't have a way of telling which of the two lists it is asked to index when it gets called by `merge`. To avoid this problem we concatenate the lists. This adds offset n+1 to indices into the second list

Comment: Paul,sorry to disturb you but i am not able to comprehend your approach.Can you please explain your approach in detail?